# How to access a JButton based on button text

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, gettext

I have a set of buttons arranged in GridLayout. I want to access a particular button based on its text. Is there any way to retrieve a button based on its text?

Comment: *"I want to access a particular button based on its text."*  Why? This has a bad code smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to iterate through the components in the panel and look for it. Something like:

```
for (Component comp : panel.getComponents())
    if (comp instanceof JButton && searchText.equals(((JButton) comp).getText()))
        return (JButton) comp;
```

However, I suggest you populate a `Map<String, JButton> buttonMap` when you create and add the buttons. You then just do `buttonMap.get(searchText)` to get hold of your button:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    JButton button = new JButton("Button " + i);
    panel.add(button);

    // save it to a map for easy retrieval
    buttonMap.put(button.getText(), button);
}
```

Comment: hmm ... don't see any advantage in keeping a map. On the contrary: it needs additional effort to keep in synch with the real ui. Walking the real thing is just fine, everything else unnessary clutter.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the components that are in your panel and simply filter the results.

```
for (Component component : getComponents()) {
    if (component instanceof JButton &&
       ((JButton) component).getText().equals(searchText)) {
        return component;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can create a Map of JButton's Name to the JButton Object**

`Map<String, JButton> mbutt = new HashMap<String, JButton>();`

**And you can access the String and JButton by iterating over it like this.**

```
for(Map.Entry<String,JButton> map : mbutt.entrySet()){

       String k = map.key();  // Key 

       JButton bu = map.value();  // JButton


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
String name= e.getActionCommand();
}
```

After adding actionListener to the all the buttons.
the name string in above code gets the String of the text that is written on the text.
after that you can handle buttons based on its text.